# R-cannot open the work directory when start

Tags: r

I try to customize my startup environment of RStudio, so I edited the **Rprofile.site** file under the etc/ directory, and it went wrong when I start.

The code of **Rprofile.site** is shown down below:

```
.First<-function(){
library(lattice)
source("H:/data")
#cat("\nWelcome at ",date(),"\n")
}

.Last<-function(){
cat("\nGoodbye at ",date(),"\n")
}
```

The error is like:

```
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'H:/data': Permission denied
```

Appreciated for any help.

Comment: Hmm, is `H:/data` a folder? Is `source` supposed to take folder as input? I don't think so.

Comment: Ahh, you probably want `setwd` and not `source` :)

Comment: The next time you ask a question I would recommend at the very least explaining exactly what it is you're trying to do.  You gave us code (thank you) but it doesn't do what you want and you didn't tell us what you want to do so we have to somehow magically divine what it is you *actually* want to do.  In this case I think jakub got it right and you just want to change the working directory. Although maybe you really do want to source an entire folder in which case I would recommend looking at the help page for source since it gives an example of how one could write a function to do just that.